# IEEEtran: spaces between words in title

Tags: latex, pdflatex, bibtex, ieee, biblatex

I have this bib item and I am using `IEEEtran` as a bibliographystyle. I have used the default `IEEEtran.bst` and `IEEEtran.cls`. I am not sure, if I need both but I have tried all variations.

```
@misc{clark_2022, 
title={Tiktok faces investigation into its impact on Young People's Mental Health}, url={https://www.theverge.com/2022/3/2/22958900/tiktok-state-ag-investigation-teens-kids-mental-physical-health}, 
journal={The Verge}, 
publisher={The Verge}, 
author={Clark, Mitchell},
year={2022}, 
month={Mar}
}
```

The reference now looks like this:

[image: citation picture]

What is causing it and how do I change it? Is this part of IEEEtran?

Comment: The problem is that your url can only be broken at a few places and to still get justified text, latex has to stretch the spaces. It will tell you about this in a warning in the log file. Try the `xurl` package. If this does not work, please add a compilable [mre]

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with IEEEtran, and adding the xurl package seemed to completely fix it.